# Merge multiple carousel items into flex grid

Tags: html, css, responsive

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If my classes aren't clear, here we have two basic carousels... However, what if we want to (on desktop screens) break these `.item` divs out of the `.carousel` parents and merge them into a flex grid with a custom order (**without manipulating the DOM with JS**).

This is what it *should* look like on desktop screens (the different colours tiles represent items from the separate carousels):

[image: Desktop]

***Note: as mentioned, this is easy to achieve with javascript, I am trying to ascertain whether it is possible to achieve it without***

Comment: since I cannot read deleted post, I cannot read your comment in last post (just a brief in inbox) :(  But I've update it as https://jsfiddle.net/ymwqkp6e/ , yes the html is different (the *another way* in last question, I think).

Comment: Hi @appleapple, thank you for you response and apologies for you not being able to see the other comment, I figured it would be better to repost the question now that it has clearer content :-). Whilst your fiddle is closer to what I am looking for, it is still not quite there. Firstly, ignore the carousel JS, this is purely an HTML/CSS question, I can sort the JS. The carousels **must** have separate containers because multiple items will be visible at once. Imagine a fixed height, with horizontal scroll style carousel. That is where the issue is...

Comment: @appleapple - See the structure in this fiddle, and then, without javascript, attempt to make the `.item` divs into a their own merge flex grid. I do not believe it is possible... https://jsfiddle.net/pf51qhtv/

Comment: thanks for your response :) yes, I agree if separate containers (and flexible height or width) is a must, then it's not possible with grid layout.  If separate containers is not a must, maybe flex layout can enable *multiple items visible at once* while keep they at one row (I'm not good at flex layout, so I'm not sure :/

Comment: @appleapple - I am 99.9% sure what I want to achieve is not possible, I am just hoping that there is a bit of CSS magic that may come to my rescue. I am really against using JS to manipulate the DOM based on responsive breakpoints. It's easy to do but in my opinion, very bad practice and should be used as last resort...

Comment: agree on that point :)

Comment: btw, you can overlap 2 grid layout to mimic tile situation if the height is constant. not good, I think.

Comment: @appleapple - yes, not ideal... I did think of that but I would consider that to be too dirty for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`.carousel {
   display: contents
}`

You can read [this interesting article](https://adrianroselli.com/2018/05/display-contents-is-not-a-css-reset.html) from which this sentence was extracted:

> In its simplest form, display: contents exists to visually remove the element’s box and replace it with its content.

And from the [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#box-generation):

> The element itself does not generate any boxes, but its children and pseudo-elements still generate boxes and text runs as normal. For the purposes of box generation and layout, the element must be treated as if it had been replaced in the element tree by its contents (including both its source-document children and its pseudo-elements, such as ::before and ::after pseudo-elements, which are generated before/after the element’s children as normal).

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8o4ev6ys/2/) with a working example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this does not answer the question. I am familiar with `display: contents` but that does not solve the issue. After looking into this, I concluded that what I wanted to achieve was not possible.

Comment: Maybe a little clarification would be useful?

Comment: See my comments on the original question :-D

Comment: I see your comments.  They are not clear i am afraid. See here:
   "....attempt to make the .item divs into a their own merge flex grid..."
Flexbox is one type of layout and Grid is another. So it is not clear which one do you want to use.